# comparing two lists with Xunit

Tags: c#, assert, xunit.net

I'm using xunit to unit test, I have a list of expected objects and a list of actual objects.  How do I compare a specific element of each object (a date) in both lists to see if they are equal? I've found the Assert.Collection method but I can't figure out how it can compare the contents of two lists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need XUnit specifics. This problem can be solved by using LINQ.

To compare an element from the list simply use:

```
Assert.True(isList[1] == shouldList[1]);
```

Just access the lists content directly. If you do not know the index, you can use LINQ:

```
Assert.True(shouldList.Any(x => x == isList[1]);
```

This will check if the `shouldList` contains any element equal to the second element in `isList`.

If you want to compare if the lists content is identical, without knowing the sequence, use something like this:

```
Assert.True(shouldList.All(shouldItem => isList.Any(isItem => isItem == shouldItem)));
```

This checks for all items in `shouldList` that at least one item in `isList` is identical.

**REMARK:**

I used the `==` operator for comparing. If this works depends on the list's content. You said you are comparing dates, here the `equals` will check for equality, not identity. For most reference types the `equals` will only compare identity. Here you have either to overwrite the default `equals` implementation or to compare custom fields and properties instead of using the `==` operator.

Comment: thanks for your help, the tests now pass.  I don't have any option to mark this as the answer though

Comment: @proteus should be the flag near the upvote button https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: ```var c1 = new int[] {1, 2, 2};
var c2 = new int[] {1, 2, 3};

Assert.True(c1.All(shouldItem => c2.Any(isItem => isItem == shouldItem)));```
This pass, but collections are different

Comment: As @Abedron noticed, I think it is not enough to check if all items in shouldList have an identical in isList. You need to check the other way around to avoid the identified problem:

`Assert.True(isList.All(isItem => shouldList.Any(shouldItem => isItem == shouldItem)));`